# How do I add the same id twice in my xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I am trying to add the same id twice (next to each other) in xml, but it keeps showing me the error and doesn't work as expected.(I would like to place these 2 blocks of code next to each other instead of one below the other,I am pretty new to android and don't have a clue on this, any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.justin.jar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#004D79"
    >
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/news_headline_padding" >

    <com.justin.jar.utils.FontTextView
        android:id="@+id/news_headline_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/common_left_padding"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" 
        foo:customFont="cabin.medium.ttf"
        android:textColor="@color/search_autosuggest_header_text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/news_headline_image" />

    <com.justin.jar.utils.FontTextView
        android:id="@+id/metadata"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/search_autosuggest_item_subtitle"
        android:textSize="12sp" 
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/common_left_padding"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/news_headline_text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/news_headline_image"
        android:layout_below="@id/news_headline_text" 
        />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/news_headline_image"
        android:layout_width="107dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/container_dropshadow"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/common_left_padding"
        android:contentDescription="@string/headline_image" 
        />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/news_headline_padding" >

    <com.justin.jar.utils.FontTextView
        android:id="@+id/news_headline_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/common_left_padding"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" 
        foo:customFont="cabin.medium.ttf"
        android:textColor="@color/search_autosuggest_header_text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/news_headline_image" />

    <com.justin.jar.utils.FontTextView
        android:id="@+id/metadata"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/search_autosuggest_item_subtitle"
        android:textSize="12sp" 
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/common_left_padding"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/news_headline_text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/news_headline_image"
        android:layout_below="@id/news_headline_text" 
        />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/news_headline_image"
        android:layout_width="107dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/container_dropshadow"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/common_left_padding"
        android:contentDescription="@string/headline_image" 
        />
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here's an example of what I want
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgfZl.png

[1]:

Comment: Ummm...give them different `id`s?

Comment: It might help to understand that XML is not code.  It is data, and the format of that data is determined by certain rules.  You cannot simply re-arrange "blocks" as you wish.

Comment: This is what I need, how do I go about it layoutwise? http://i.stack.imgur.com/TgfZl.png

Comment: The linked image does not seem to be related to this question. Rotten url?

Answer (score 1):

[From the Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

> ID
>
> Any View object may have an integer ID associated with it, to uniquely
>   identify the View within the tree.

Change the `id` of one. For instance

```
<com.justin.jar.utils.FontTextView
android:id="@+id/news_headline_text_right"
```

You can have `View`s with the same `id` in different `resource` files, I believe, although I don't think its a good idea. But within the tree they have to be unique or else Android wouldn't know which one to use when you try to access it with, say, `findViewById()`

Comment: its not true: you can have the same ids even within one layout file, why not?

Comment: @pskink Wrong. Try to attach any listeners to an ID with multiple reference points in one layout file, your app will crash.

Comment: I am just trying to place 2 relativelayout blocks next to each other, but they are using the same id from java code as in news_headlines for instance, I cant change that in java code as I am modifying just for the table,t keeping the phone code same and so these changes in layouts go under large and xlarge folders, any idea how I can get around this?

Comment: You mean for.ex. OnClickListener? if so you add it the Views not IDs

Comment: @JusticeBauer I'm afraid I don't understand what you are talking about... Can you better explain what you want to change and why you want the `id`s to be the same?

Comment: take a ListView as an example: it can have hundrets Sams and yet it works

Comment: I am talking about say one block has image and news headline and another has the same (both are using the same id, which is populated as per the java cde set),I want to place these 2 blocks next to each other, so their id's don't show a warning even when I use the same id's, would it help if I provide a screenshot?

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you need the same `id`s to do that. You simply assign one set of data to the `id` on the left and the other set to the `id` on the right

Comment: I have explained it in a much easier and detailed way here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058491/how-do-i-call-2-consecutive-items-in-a-list-in-a-table-form-next-to-each-other , please check and lemme know if you have an idea about it ? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the ID proprety must be a unique proprety to every object in your project. so if you make  two or more object with the same ID, this will not generate any error, but the compiler will use the first one he meets. why do you need this anyway ??

Answer (score 0):

ID's **cannot** be used multiple times within one XML document. They have to be unique.

Comment: @pskink Wrong. Try to attach any listeners to an ID with multiple reference points in one layout file, your app will crash.